# Open file on plug-in USB

Tags: file, jar, usb, autoplay, plug-and-play

Can anyone tell me how to open a .jar file when you plug your USB in a laptop? Write a batch file? Or what do I need?

I've read about it that it's only available on windows, so it's not possible on a MAC. But isn't there a way to open a window on mac, and say 'click here to start'?

So this questions has 2 parts:

1. How can i open a file when I plug in a USB on windows?
2. If it's not available on mac - what other possibilities do i have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows you're probably looking for [AutoRun.inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf). Though remember that this might have been disabled on the computer.

Comment: Yes, something like that. Do you have experience with it? I just made a file 'autorun.inf', but i would like to open a .jar file. Now it just stored it as another drive.

the code I used is ` [autorun] 
open=pdflist.jar
icon=pdflist.jar,0
label=List of available PDFs`

Comment: @Killerwes: Sorry, not really a java guy so don't know much about Jar files, but is it possible that instead of having `open=pdflist.jar`, maybe you could try something like `open=java -jar pdflist.jar`?

Comment: Yeah, I've found that too and tried it. But it doesn't open. I guess they will just have to double click it :p